# Other images in Ansible and GCE

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine, ansible

I am trying to create an Ubuntu machine from the gce module in Ansible,
I am able to create a debian-7 machine without any problem with the following playbook (change  the image to "debian-7" :

```
- name: Create Compute Engine instances
  hosts: local
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
 vars:
   names: webserver-sr01
   machine_type: n1-standard-1
   image: ubuntu-1404
   zone: us-central1-a
   email: 12345678-longhash@developer.gserviceaccount.com
   pid: fakeproj
pem: ~/Certs/somthing.pem
 tasks:
   - name: Launch instances
     gce:
      instance_names: "{{ names }}"
      machine_type: "{{ machine_type }}"
      image: "{{ image }}"
      service_account_email: "{{ email }}"
      pem_file: "{{ pem }}"
      project_id: "{{ pid }}"
      tags: docker-pubzilla-ws
     register: gce
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I literally ran into this same issue about 3 weeks ago. I'm guessing that you installed the release version of the libcloud library which is where the issue is. This is because the release version doesn't have support for ubuntu yet where as the development version does:

https://github.com/apache/libcloud/blob/trunk/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py

Search for "ubuntu" in the file above and you'll see the conditional that checks for it. If you compare it to the gce.py file that is in your local which for me was under,

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/comput/drivers/gce.py
```

you'll see that ubuntu isn't there.

In order to work around this, you'll need to install the development version as detailed here:

https://libcloud.apache.org/getting-started.html

which pretty much involves doing:

```
pip install  git+https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/libcloud.git@trunk#egg=apache-libcloud
```

It's possible that pip will detect that you already have libcloud installed so you might need to remove your current version first.

Comment: check also the image name.  I had an issue where I used ubuntu-1404 as it was the alias I saw somewhere, but if you do a gcloud compute instances list, you'll see the alias is ubuntu-14-04.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than providing the name of the image, provide the full url to the image. You had:

```
image: ubuntu-1404
```

Change it to:

```
image: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20150128
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include more of an explanation here.

Comment: Nathan, that's not a link, but a line of code for a `gce` Ansible task. Fully valid answer IMHO. The essence is, you can add an URL, not only the name of an `image`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the image names mentioned at [cloud sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create), which are:

1. centos-6
2. centos-7
3. container-vm
4. coreos-stable
5. debian-7-wheezy
6. backports-debian-7-wheezy
7. debian-8-jessie
8. opensuse-13
9. rhel-6
10. rhel-7
11. sles-11
12. sles-12
13. ubuntu-1204-precise
14. ubuntu-1404-trusty
15. ubuntu-1410-utopic
16. ubuntu-1504-vivid
17. windows-server-2008-r2
18. windows-server-2012-r2